# Magento 2 : Add to Wishlist not Appearing on Product Page

Tags: magento2, product, wishlist, parent-child-theme

When the store is using `custom child theme` design, `add to wishlist` is not appearing on the product page.

When I switch to other theme, it appears.

What could be the reason?

---

UPDATE:

I realised that when I have catalog_product_view.xml under my custom theme in Magento_Catalog/layout, `add to wishlist` is not appearing.

Comment: I have added the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/70302695/1468900

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You Just needed to copy

```
module_wishlist/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml
```

to

```
Magento_Wishlist/layout/catalog_product_view.xml
```

Under custom theme.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem in Magento 2.3.0. In my custom theme I changed layout of catalog_product_view.xml and "Add To Wishlist" stopped showing up. Any change to the file and it wouldn't be visible. So I called it manually:

```
<block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Catalog\Product\View\AddTo\Wishlist" name="wishlist" as="wishlist" template="Magento_Wishlist::catalog/product/view/addto/wishlist.phtml"/>
```

Add it anywhere in the code but this will work only in "Product Details". If you want to show it in product listing use following:

```
<block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Catalog\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Wishlist" name="wishlist" as="wishlist" template="Magento_Wishlist::catalog/product/list/addto/wishlist.phtml"/>
```

I didn't checked if this works properly in product listing but it should.